# Why am I getting Exception in thread error?

Tags: java

I am trying to make this program That uses the scanner method. A user would type their name, then the `ScannerTool`class would store that information into the `guess` string varible. An Object is created in the `portation` class as `ScannerTool cool = new ScannerTool();` for both the `justPoints()` and `post()` methods. The `portation` class takes the objects and store what the user types into a String variable called `hope` as `String hope = cool.scannerT()` it then takes what the user types and executes an if statement. I create an object for the `portation` class and `ScannerTool` inside the MainTest and then I run it from `MainTest` class.

My problem is that when I run this program it throws an exception error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at ScannerTool.scannerT(ScannerTool.java:7)
    at portation.justPoints(portation.java:12)
    at MainTest.main(MainTest.java:20)
```

However, when i dont use the `portation` class and just go from `ScannerTool` to `MainTest` with the same code from `portation` it works. The weird part is that when I do it the original way there are no errors presented at the lines, only when I execute the whole program

What I tried: I tried to change the return types in the methods in `portation` from int and string to void, that didn't work. I tried looking at the lines that said where the error occured, but that didn't help becuase everything looked correct. Since it's not throwing actual errors on the IDE before running i'm at a loss.

the code:

The code that works:
MainTest

```
public class MainTest {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        
        ScannerTool scan = new ScannerTool();
        //portation damn = new portation ();
        System.out.print("What your name my guy? ");
        String hope = scan.scannerT();
        
        int points = 0; // taken from the portation class
        if (hope.equals("chris")){
            
            points = points + 1;
            
        }else {
            points = 0;
            
        }
        
        System.out.println("the name " + hope  + " is cool");
        
        if(hope.equals("chris")) {
            
            System.out.println("for your name being chris I award you one point!");
            
        }else {
            System.out.println("but, you get no points for that name");
            
        } //taken from the portation class
        
    
        System.out.println(points);
        
        
        
        

        //damn.post();

        
        //damn.justPoints();

    }

}
```

```
portation: not in use
```

ScannerTool:

```
import java.util.*;
public class ScannerTool {
    
    public String scannerT() {
        Scanner message = new Scanner(System.in); //User input
        
        String guess = message.nextLine(); // storing what the user inputted in a string variable
         

        message.close(); //closed the scanner object
        
    
        
        return guess; // returned user input
        
    }

}
```

the code that doesn't work
MaintTest:

```
public class MainTest {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        
        ScannerTool scan = new ScannerTool();
        portation damn = new portation ();
        System.out.print("What your name my guy? ");
        String hope = scan.scannerT();
        damn.post();

        
        damn.justPoints();
        
    }

}
```

portation:

```
public class  portation {

    public void justPoints() {
        ScannerTool cool = new ScannerTool(); // created an object from the ScannerTool
        String hope = cool.scannerT(); //stored the ScannerTool answer the user inputed from the guess string
        int points = 0; //setup the points variable
        if (hope.equals("chris")){
            
            points = points + 1;
            
        }else {
            points = 0;
            
        }
        System.out.println(points);
        
    }
    public void post() {
        ScannerTool cool = new ScannerTool(); // created an object from the ScannerTool
        String hope = cool.scannerT(); //stored the ScannerTool answer the user inputed from the guess string
        System.out.println("the name " + hope  + " is cool"); //printed what the user typed
        
        if(hope.equals("chris")) {
            
            System.out.println("for your name being chris I award you one point!");
            
        }else {
            System.out.println("but, you get no points for that name");
            
        }
        
        
        
    }
}
```

ScannerTool:

```
import java.util.*;
public class ScannerTool {
    
    public String scannerT() {
        Scanner message = new Scanner(System.in); //User input
        
        String guess = message.nextLine(); // storing what the user inputted in a string variable
         

        message.close(); //closed the scanner object
        
    
        
        return guess; // returned user input
        
    }

}
```

when I use the way that doesn't work this is what runs:

```
What your name my guy? chris
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at ScannerTool.scannerT(ScannerTool.java:7)
    at portation.post(portation.java:21)
    at MainTest.main(MainTest.java:9)
```

What would be the answer I'm looking for? I would like to know, why am I getting this error and what do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: Did you read the error message carefully? `Scanner.nextLine` in `ScannerTool` line 7 failed, because no more lines were found in the input.

Comment: @Amongalen because that's all there was after that, the only thing that's left is me closing the scanner and returning the value

Comment: @Amongalen also i dont have Scanner.nextLine in ScannerTool that's in the actual Scanner class that java provides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that `System.in` is a specific `InputStream` - it is static and only created once. In your case, you read from it once and immediately close it (when you close the `Scanner`). When you try to read from a closed stream, it will throw an exception, `NoSuchElementException` in this case. When working with files it usually isn't a problem because you could always create a new InputStream.

What you need to do here is to make sure you will close the InputStream only when you're done with reading everything. You could make the `Scanner` variable static, create a new method for closing it and call it only when you're done with reading.

Comment: so if i want to close it in the portation how would i apply the varible static method?

Comment: Probably your best bet is to close it only inside of the `main` method itself.

Comment: that's what i'm tryin to figure out now, how would i go about doin that lol